# How to run Capybara/Poltergeist on localhost in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, capybara, poltergeist

Trying to get some headless UI smoke testing going on Jenkins builds.  Looks like [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) will be the way to go, but I'm having trouble getting the driver to pick up any content.

Current strategy is to compile all of the assets as if a production deployment is going to occur.

**Step One: Make a "localhost production deployment"**

```
bundle install --deployment --retry=3
npm install
cd client # where all React.js code lives
node_modules/.bin/webpack -b --config webpack.production.config
cd ..
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
mkdir -p public/images;
cp -R app/assets/images/* public/images/
```

**Step Two: Run localhost:3000 in production mode**

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
```

**Step Three: Run smoke tests that point towards localhost:3000**

```
bundle exec rspec spec/features
```

Here my extremely trivial test example for capybara/poltergeist:

```
require "rails_helper"

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"

RSpec.describe "FooBar copyright", js: true do
  context "when on the homepage" do
    it "displays 'All rights reserved'" do
      Rails.env = "production"
      page.visit "/"
      expect(page).to have_content "All rights reserved"
    end
  end
end
```

---

You would think this would work... It doesn't though.  The tests are failing because they are not picking up any content.  I have done some debugging, and the Rails.env is correct and the `current_url` is also properly set to `localhost:3000`.

Manually going to `localhost:3000` in the browser works fine as well.  The assets are compiling correctly.

For some reason capybara/poltergeist is simply not picking up the content.  Get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "All rights reserved"
   expected to find text "All rights reserved" in ""
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Since you're running against an "external" app, you shouldn't be setting Rails.env in the test, although I don't think it would cause your current issue you should remove that.  What does `page.html` respond with after the visit?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole great thought.  `page.html` returns what's in my application layout along with the `<div id="react-entry">`.  So, the html is being returned... but the javascript is not somehow.  When I take a screenshot, I get a completely blank page.

Comment: Make sure you're using phantomjs 2.1.1 - phantomjs < 2 doesn't support Function.prototype.bind which react requires.  Beyond that, no current version of phantomjs supports ES6/2105+ so if you're using any of those features and not transpiling to ES5 compatible code your tests won't work.  You can try configuring your poltergeist driver to show JS errors - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization - which will show runtime errors.  If you're using anything like `let` though it will trigger a parsetime error which phantomjs doesn't report.

Comment: Also, try sleeping a few seconds before calling page.html or taking a screenshot - it's possible you are calling those before the JS fully renders (if there aren't any errors in it)